# How can I get google map places autocomplete in searchbar in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have try to get list of user search related locations is auto populated in search bar in Xamarin forms but I can't able find any solution. Please suggest any idea for getting list of location based user search text in search bar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code, people won't code from scratch for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can look the sample autocompletion into the TK.CustomMap repository.
TK.CustomMap is an override implementation of Xamarin.Forms.Maps.

Project:
https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap

Sample: https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/tree/Development/Source/Samples/Sample/TK.CustomMap.Sample

The autocompletion can be used with Google API for location (or other provider like OpenStreetMap).